# Mocha: Multiple "it" calls in single server request

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to test 40+ API endpoints using Mocha. I would like to perform a few subtests as a part of a single server call.

For example, I would like to test if `it('returns valid JSON...` and `it('returns a valid status code...`, etc.

```
configs.forEach(function(config) {

    describe(config.endpoint, () => {

        it('...', function(done) {
            server
                .post(config.endpoint)
                .send({})
                .expect('Content-type', /json/)
                .expect(200)
                .end(function(err, res) {

                    //it('has a proper status code', () => {
                    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
                    //})

                    //it('does not have an error object', () => {
                    expect(res.body.hasOwnProperty('error')).toEqual(false);
                    //})

                    done();
                })
        })

    })

})
```

The problem is that I cannot nest `it` statements, but I am relying on the callback, via `done()` to dictate when the response has been received, so I have to wrap the call in an `it` statement...

Because some of these requests take half of a second to resolve, and there are 40+ of them, I *don't* want to create separate tests for these. Creating separate tests would also duplicate the config.endpoint, and I'd like to see if the tests are passing for each endpoint all in one place.

**How can I create multiple tests for a single server call?**

Comment: Mock callback, It think it will make easy ?

Comment: Mock the callback from `it(...`? Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I accomplished this, using mocha, chai, and supertest (API requests):

```
import { expect } from "chai"

const supertest = require("supertest");
const BASE_URL = process.env.API_BASE_URL || "https://my.api.com/";
let api = supertest(BASE_URL);

describe("Here is a set of tests that wait for an API response before running.", function() {

  //Define error & response in the 'describe' scope. 
  let error, response;

  //Async stuff happens in the before statement.
  before(function(done) {
    api.get("/dishes").end(function(err, resp) {
      error = err, response = resp;
      done();
    });
  });

  it("should return a success message", function() {
    console.log("I have access to the response & error objects here!", response, error);
    expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
  });

  it("should return an array of foos", function() {
    expect(response.body.data.foo).to.be.an("array");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    configs.forEach(function(config) {

        describe(config.endpoint, () => {

            var response;    
            it('...', function(done) {
                server
                    .post(config.endpoint)
                    .send({})
                    .expect('Content-type', /json/)
                    .expect(200)
                    .end(function(err, res) {
                          response=res;
                          done();  
                      })
             });

                    it('has a proper status code', () => {
                          expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
                    })

                    it('does not have an error object', () => {
                            expect(response.body.hasOwnProperty('error')).toEqual(false);
                    })

         })
})
```

What about this ? 
I am not sure about nesting of test cases but it will work for u.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the test order. In this case you rely on the fact that the first `it` executes before the following two.